# Solving system of super-ellipse equations

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, systems-of-equations

Super-ellipses are the equations that yield unit circles in different p-norms in $L^p$ space. I'm interested in the solution space in the unit square. My trouble is finding the solutions that are neither on the line $x=1/2$ nor on the line $y=1/2$. How do the following equations relate to $L^p$ space and how does one solve this system of super-ellipse equations for

$s,t=1,2,3.$ That is, what is the solution space for the intersections of these $6$ super-ellipse equations for,

$ x,y \in \Bbb R (0,1). $

The system is:

$ x^s+y^s=1 $

$ (1-x)^t+y^t=1. $

For $s=2$ and $t=3$ I first foiled, then added the equations and simplified to arrive at the following:

$-x^3+4x^2-3x+y^2+y^3=1.$

I know the solution must be algebraic.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood something, but from the system we obtain $x^s=(1-x)^s$, so $|x|=|1-x|$. That is $x$ is a midpoint of a segment $[0,1]$, so $x=1/2$.

Comment: Normally the second equation would be $x^t+y^t=1$.  There are no intersections except $(\pm 1,0)$ and $(0,\pm 1)$ because increasing the exponent drives the curve from a diagonal square to the orthogonal square monotonically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your $s=2,t=3$ example, which is the hardest, you can write 
$$(1-x)^3=1-y^3\\ 1-x=\sqrt[3]{1-y^3}\\
1-\sqrt{1-y^2}=\sqrt[3]{1-y^3}$$
which will give you a sixth degree polynomial when you clear the roots.  [Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1-sqrt(1-x%5E2)%3Dcbrt(1-x%5E3)) finds a root that is messy enough it gives it numerically as about $y=0.919311$